# Automatically changing folder icon using python (windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, automation, windows-10, icons

I am making a program to rename some **folders** and also change their icon using python.
I am able to manage the renaming part, but I am not able to change the icon.

I have tried:

- using `os.system()` and executing commands from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095448/how-to-change-existing-folders-icon-via-command-line-windows-10).There are no errors but the icons do not change. (also after refreshing)

Thank you!

P.S. I am NOT trying to make all icons the same, I am using some logic which selects the icon based on the folder name, and the logic works as proven by print statements...